# Check if Current Azure CloudDrive is mounted

Tags: azure

`Azure CloudDrive.Unmount()` will give exception

```
[InteropCloudDriveException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive.Interop.InteropCloudDriveException' was thrown.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive.Interop.InteropCloudDrive.Unmount(String urlOrMountPoint) +348
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudDrive.Unmount() +71
```

When there's not drive been mounted.

My question is: is there a way to check if current clouddrive is mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CloudDrive.GetMountedDrives(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.getmounteddrives.

Comment: Ohh, right, each Uri can only mount once in each instance. I was misunderstand the snapshot and thought it can mount as readonly for multiple time. Thanks